# SuportMapFragment in a row of listView

Tags: android, google-maps, android-listview, expandablelistview

I have an activity that has a ExpandableListView in each cell I want to display a map with a alfinete.Vou post my code and the error I'm having.

In my Main:

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity {
    .....
    private void refreshListView ( ) {
        ListAdapterDetalhes ListAdapterDetalhes adapter = new (this, items ) ;
        list.setAdapter ( adapter ) ;
    }
    .....

}
```

My adapter:

....

```
    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Object content = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        // Mostra célula com o text View
        if(content.getClass().equals(String.class)){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_detalhes_texto, null);

            TextView descricao = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_descricao_estabelecimento);
            descricao.setText((String)content);

        }
        // Mostra tabela com os Telefones, Emails e o site
        else if(content.getClass().equals(Contato.class)){

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_detalhes_contato, null);
            List<ItemContato> itens = Util.testaCamposContato((Contato)content,activity);
            ListView list = (ListView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.listContato);
            ListAdapterContato adapter = new ListAdapterContato(itens,activity);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);

            // Redimenciona listView
            Util.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(list);


        }
        // Mostra a célula com o endereço e o mapa
        else if(content.getClass().equals(Endereco.class)){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_detalhes_endereco, null);

            TextView textEndereco = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_texto_endereco);
            Endereco endereco = (Endereco)content;
            String strEndereco = ""+endereco.getLogradouro() + ", " +endereco.getNumero()
                    +"\n" + endereco.getBairro() + "\n" + endereco.getCep()
                    +"\n" + endereco.getComplemento()
                    +"\n" + endereco.getCidade().getNome() + " - RS / Brasil";

            textEndereco.setText(strEndereco);

            // Verifica se o Google play services está instalado no aparelho do usuário
            int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity.getBaseContext());

            // Se não estiver mostra um alerta de notificação
            if(status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available
                Util.alerta(Util.getString(R.string.S0x0001, activity), Util.getString(R.string.S0x0044, activity), activity);
                Log.e("ERRO", "google play problem");

            }else { // Google play Services está instalado, mostra o pino no mapa
                //Mostra pino no mapa com as coordenaas 
                this.populate_map(endereco.getLatitude(),endereco.getLongitude(),
                                  endereco.getGenericEstab().getNome(),null,
                                  R.drawable.pizzarias,18,activity,convertView);
            }
        }
}

/**
 * Fixa o pino com as coordenadas e faz todos ajustes necessários
 * no MapView
 */
public void populate_map( double lat, double lng, String title, String description,
                         int icon, int zoom, Context context, View v){
    //Atribui ID para o MapView
    // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment of activity_main.xml
    SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapDetalhes);
    GoogleMap map = fm.getMap();

    map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(lat, lng))
            .title(title)
            .snippet(description)
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(icon)));

    // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), zoom));

    // Zoom in, animating the camera.
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(zoom), 2000, null);

}
```

....

XML address details (cell )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/root">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Endereço"
            android:id="@+id/item_texto_endereco"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>



        <fragment
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/mapDetalhes"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/item_texto_endereco"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
           />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My code is complex because it is an adapter that displays the layout according to the type of the object , everything works fine , exeto with the layout of the map , I get the following error:

> 02-12 11:37:55.674  11799-11799/com.mobsolution.turismogaribaldi
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #32: Error inflating class fragment
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:697)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
>               at genericestab.ListAdapterDetalhes.getChildView(ListAdapterDetalhes.java:150)
>               at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:455)
>               at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2464)
>               at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250)
>               at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1161)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12842)
>               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
>               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12842)
>               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:579)
>               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:392)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12842)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4712)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12842)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4712)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12842)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4712)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1385)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:670)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:563)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12842)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4712)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2242)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12842)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1240)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2632)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #32: Duplicate id 0x7f07007f, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with
>   another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
>               at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:296)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:669)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:742)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
>               at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
>               at genericestab.ListAdapterDetalhes.getChildView(ListAdapterDetalhes.java:150)
>               at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:455)
>               at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2464)
>               at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1250)
>               at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1161)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12842)
>               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:594)
>               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:376)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12842)
>               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:579)
>               at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:392)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12842)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4712)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12842)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4712)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12842)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4712)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1385)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:670)
>               at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:563)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12842)
>               at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4712)
>               at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:293)
>               at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2242)
>               at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12842)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1240)
>               at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2632)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4517)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:993)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:760)
>               at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: did you try removing `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` from fragment in xml?

Comment: I tried what you said but still the same error!